# Двоеточие после "например"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие

Можно ли поставить двоеточие вместо запятых в предложении: "Вот, например, стоит он перед окном, смотрит вдаль и думает"?

> Вот например: стоит он перед окном, смотрит вдаль и думает.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что оба варианта постановки знаков возможны.

14) Слово ***например*** связано со следующей пунктуацией:

а) выделяется запятыми как вводное: Николай Артемьевич любил настойчиво поспорить, например, о том, можно ли человеку в течение всей своей жизни объездить весь земной шар (Т.);

б) выделяется запятыми вместе с оборотом, в начале или в конце которого находится: Даже в городах, например в Москве, когда тронется мелководная Москва-река, все её берега и мосты бывают усыпаны народом (Акс.); Вопросом заинтересовались и другие, я например;

в) требует постановки запятой перед собой и двоеточия после себя, если стоит после обобщающего слова перед перечислением однородных членов предложения: Некоторые грибы очень ядовиты, например: бледная поганка, сатанинский гриб, мухомор.[Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html)

Answer (score 2):

Это зависит от контекста. Можно - в случае, если данное предложение завершает предшествующее высказывание, а часть предложения после двоеточия исчерпывающе раскрывает ранее сказанное.

```
Он очень задумчив и рассеян. 
Вот например: стоит он перед окном, смотрит  вдаль и думает. С чего бы?
```

С запятой же напрашивается продолжение "примера" (На его плечо садится попугай, а он этого даже не замечает...).